# What examples highlight the difference between 感情 (gǎnqíng) and 情感 (qínggǎn), meaning "emotion" [noun]?

Tags: difference

Both [感情](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%84%9F%E6%83%85) (gǎnqíng) and [情感](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%83%85%E6%84%9F) (qínggǎn) are nouns that mean "emotion".  Some examples:

> 这复杂的**情感**使埃拉想起了自己的丈夫。<sup>[[src]](http://www.jukuu.com/show-%E6%83%85%E6%84%9F-7.html)</sup>
> These complex emotions cause Ella to think of her own husband.
>
> 最后这种感情再也抑制不了。<sup>[[src]](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%84%9F%E6%83%85)</sup>
> Finally, these kinds of emotions [are] no longer inhibiting.

I can't see a difference.  I found [a Baidu Zhidao article](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/453809590.html) which I translate below, which asserts there is a difference, but it didn't help me understand what the difference is.  Ideally, it would be nice to have concrete examples which identify the difference.

**Question**: What examples highlight the difference between 感情 and 情感?

---

From [感情和情感有区别吗？](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/453809590.html)

> 有区别。
>
> There's a difference.
>
> 情感是态度这一整体中的一部分，它与态度中的内向感受、意向具有协调一致性，是态度在生理上一种较复杂而又稳定的生理评价和体验。情感包括道德感和价值感两个方面，具体表现为爱情、幸福、仇恨、厌恶、美感等等。
>
> 情感 is the entirety of 态度 ("attitude"), inside it and 态度 we feel and incline to have coordinated consistency.  It's 态度 physiology's comparatively complicated and stable physiological evaluation and self-experience.  情感 includes feelings of virtue and value; concrete expressions of romance, happiness, hatred, loathing, sense of beauty, and so on.
>
> 而感情，是人内心的各种的感觉、思想和行为的一种综合的心理和生理状态，是对外界刺激所产生的心理反应，以及附带的生理反应。如：喜、怒、哀、乐等，感情是个人的主观体验和感受，常跟心情、气质、性格和性情有关。
>
> While 感情, is a person's internal kind of 感情, thoughts and behaviors in a composite mental and physiological state.  It's the external world which provokes and give rise to mental reaction, as well as incidental physiological reactions.  For example, like, anger, sorry, happiness.  感情 is a personal subjective experience and sense, commonly related with mood, temperament, disposition, and nature.

In my mind, that's a lot of words, and very little clarity.  (And it's also just "some random person on the Internet said so", which is unreliable.)

Comment: Dictionary from Ministry of Education in Taiwan(traditional Chinese): [感情](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000070156) [情感](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000102639). Please note that some of usages are archaic and seldom used by people now.

Answer (score 2):

I think 感情 usually means the emotion between you and someone or something. For example:
我和他是十多年的老朋友了，我们的感情很深。
你和她有感情吗？
我对祖国有着深厚的感情。

While 情感 is a broader concept.
悲伤、仇恨、惋惜多种情感交织在一起，让她的心情久久不能平静。

Answer (score 2):

百度知道 answers it very well.

If you still have a hard time understanding it, you can simply take it that 感情 is **bearing an affection for something** and 情感 is **your emotional(情) feelings(感)** such as *love, hatred, sadness, anger, etc*.

E.g. 我对她是有感情的 // I bear an affection for her.

爱恨交织在一起的情感 // 爱 and 恨 are two kinds of 情感, which are twisted together.

Answer (score 2):

My explanation:-

感情 are the deep person-to-person emotions felt and conveyed between two or more persons. Like the love and affections between a man and a woman, a parent and child, two intimate friends. In other words emotional sentiments between people at a personal level. And could often be conveyed by "I love / miss you"

情感 while describing emotional states in general, nevertheless extends to encompass other wider, general emotional states like sympathy, empathy, charity, sadness, friendship, (perhaps even including the so-called Stockholm Syndrome); And could be conveyed by "I am sorry for your loss"; "You are in my prayers"

Example:-

他们的好友情感渐渐变成了深爱感情:-

Their feelings of close friendship gradually changed to deep love.

Answer (score 1):

要辨析这两个词我们还要看第三个词：情绪。

情绪是人在境遇下最**直接和浅层心理活动的概括**，如喜、怒、哀、惧等。情感则为**更高级心理活动的概括**，如：

- 复杂的情感郁结于胸，久不能息。丈夫又彻夜不归，他究竟是忙于工作吗？会不会另有新欢？不，他向来是爱自己的，决不可能犯错。于是又不免担心起来，他是不是应酬醉酒，露宿街头了？

由此，情感更为具体于情境，通常简单一二字难以概括，所以我们经常使用如“复杂的情感”等，先引出其事，再另辟文字以详析。当然许多情感确有式范，如上述段落，若不需要解释清楚，也可以写作：

- 猜疑、自宽又不免担忧，丈夫夜不归宿使她心头郁结着复杂的情感。

感情则是一种**具有对象的情感**。所以爱、恨、仇、厌等既是感情，又是情感：

- 最后这种感情再也压抑不住。他展幅挥毫，恣意将心中对祖国的热爱图画在案上的壮丽山河之中。

感情作为**取对象的情感**，一般是逐渐形成，较为稳定的，这时我们可以用“深厚”来形容一种稳固的感情。也因此，人与人之间的感情**也指人与人之间的关系、态度等**。

- 我与他是感情深厚的老友了。
- 夫妻之间感情和睦。

P.S. 百度知道 is often inaccurate even misleading, because now few people use it, and thus it lacks voting and editing.

P.P.S.

双语例句的缺点在于，其中一方并非一定是自然原文，而可能是机器翻译；即便是人工翻译，水平亦参差不齐。在翻译机器大行其道的当下，许多偷懒的人完全依赖于此而不去辨析语境，向互联网添加名为人翻实为机翻的语料，加之翻译机器的学习基础又是采集互联网的语料数据，形成自我强化的闭环，久之确实影响到了原本语言的精密和纯净，使得许多人，包括母语人士，都不辨词义，不工句式。母语人士尚受荼毒，更毋论学习者了。中文如是，世界通行之英语亦然。这大概是语言发展的规律叭～

Comment: Man, anyone understanding this would not need to ask about the difference between 感情 and 情感 了.

Comment: @WayneCheah I believe the OP can understand the answer with minor efforts... What she asks is the difference of 感情 & 情感, but sadly it would take me a lot of time to deal with such subtle difference in English, and I think write in Chinese could possibly help the OP with writing as well. But I will convert it to English if I have time...hhh